# Retrieving data from related tables via EF6 and Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've used the Code First process to create several SQL tables.

```
public class Person
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public TitleType Title { get; set; }
}
public class TitleType
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I am using the following syntax to retrieve a Person.

```
Person person= db.Persons.Find(id);
```

I an access the attributes of the person properly but shouldn't I be able to access the TitleType Name property with

```
var MyTitle = person.Title.Name;
```

Is my code first code structured correctly or do I need to change some relationship?
Currently it just returns a null.

---

Here is my Context class

```
 public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }
    public MyContext()
        : base("Name=MyContext")
    {
    }
   public DbSet<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
   public DbSet<TitleType> TitleTypes { get; set; }

           protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }               
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions at run-time?

Comment: Can you also post your context class?

Comment: No exceptions at run-tme.

Comment: Just added context  class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have lazy loading disabled. Try following to load `Title` property content eagerly:

```
Person person= db.Persons.Include("Title").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: I thought I had lazy loading enabled.. Your change worked but now I need to get lazy loading working.

Comment: @JohnS Are you trying to access `Title` property when context is still open? It's quite common issue to have it already closed when navigation property is requested, so no query to db can be made. And btw. why do you need Lazy Loading? Loading content eagerly performs better, because you have only one db query send to database.

Comment: Performance is not so much an issue for this app. I'm more concerned with simplification of the code and thought I could get that this way.

Comment: To get lazy loading working, put virtual in front of the type for the cross-table variable. I.E. public virtual TitleType Title